# can't sort data int properly with gridview

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview

I want to sort my integer data, but I want to make it easier to read, if I have data like `1000000000` I want it display `1,000,000,000` so I use this query in mysql;

```
format(col_name,0)
```

I tried to sort it with sort function in C# using gridview, I use this to sort gridview;

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    tempExp = e.SortExpression;
    Session["sort"] = tempExp;
    showData();
}
void showData()
{
    tempExp = (string)Session["sort"];
    sortProperty = SortDirection.Descending;
    sortedView = new DataView(dataset); 
    sortedView.Sort = tempExp + " Desc"; 
    GridView1.DataSource = sortedView; 
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

but this is what happen when I tried to sort data2;

```
+================+=================+
|     data1      |      data2      |
+================+=================+
|     21,039,000 |               6 |
|     30,080,000 |           4,062 |
|    209,120,040 |          28,692 |
|    201,200,900 |           2,115 |
|      1,100,900 |          15,858 |
+================+=================+
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: How can you expect it to be sorted if you're not applying a sorting function?

Comment: In general I would not apply formatting of numbers in the SQL queries. That's what the user interface is for. There is a [How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s(v=vs.100).aspx) which might help you.

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL?  If you can do the sorting in SQL, please show the query.  If not, remove the tag.

Comment: I read [How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s(v=vs.100).aspx) and I use `this.dataGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";` I already add namspace `System.Windows.Forms` and add reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` but `DefaultCellStyle` still can't be found

Comment: Why not sort it in mySQL before passing it to the DataGridView?

Comment: @Edper I have more than 1 column to sort,as example data1 and data2, so I use gridviewsorting function, so user can sort either data1 or data2

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Now, try to check @student080705639 my solution/answer that I provided below.

Comment: @student080705639 Would you care to explain the un-acceptance after the acceptance?

Comment: @Edper my first acceptance is a mistake, I haven't tried it, after I try it turns out `GridView1.Columns ['A']. Visible = false;` displays error, I already put it after I assigned it to `DataSource` but it's still not working, it says `Index was out of range`

Comment: Hello @student080705639 thanks for the response. I tested it in my own PC and it works fine without any error. I will soon get back at you if I could find possible solution that caters to your situation.

Comment: @Edper I forgot to say that I change your code, I didnt use `String newSort = tempExp == 'Data1' ? 'A' : 'B';` because I have 5 different data, so I use `if(tempExp == "data1") newSort = "A";` etc, was that the cause of the error?

Comment: That's fine but did you change your query also like SELECT Data1 as A, format(Data1,0) as 'Data1', Data2 as B, format(Data2,0) as 'Data2', Data3 as C, format(Data3,0) as 'Data3', Data4 as D, format(Data4,0) as 'Data4', Data5 as E, format(Data5,0) as 'Data5' FROM `tabletest`. Don'T forget to DEBUG to see what's the actual value of newSort just to make sure it is not the source of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution**:

Do the formatting in C# code.

```
int num = 11111111;
string s = num.ToString("N0");
```

**Second solution**:

Include the original  int columns in the sql query along with the formatted value & apply the sort on original int columns & bind the formatted columns in gridview for display.

Answer (score 0):

One solution probably is in your query in mySQL you will both have the formatted version and unformatted version of both `Data1` and `Data2` and then sort it according to the un-formatted version, so your query would look like this:

```
SELECT Data1 as A, format(Data1,0) as 'Data1', 
Data2 as B, format(Data2,0) as 'Data2' 
FROM `tabletest`
```

And then if the user click to Sort using `Data1` then you will sort it in `'A'` (alias for Data1 above) instead of `Data1` (formatted version) but if by `Data2` then in `'B'` (again as Alias). So, that your code will look this:

```
void showData()
{
 tempExp = (string)Session["sort"];
 sortProperty = SortDirection.Descending;
 sortedView = new DataView(dataset);
 String newSort = tempExp == 'Data1' ? 'A' : 'B'; // Use the Alias to sort 
 sortedView.Sort = newSort + " Desc"; 
 GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;
 GridView1.Columns['A'].Visible = false; // Hide sorting column A to the user
 GridView1.Columns['B'].Visible = false; // Hide sorting column B to the user
 GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

So, if you observe there I just check first which column the user wants to sort and switch it to the non-formatted Sorter column which is either 'A' (for `Data1`) or 'B' (for `Data2`) like:

```
String newSort = tempExp == 'Data1' > 'A' : 'B'; // Use the Alias to sort 
sortedView.Sort = newSort + " Desc";
```

And then hide the Sorter columns from user's eyes but be sure to put it after it is assigned to `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` otherwise you have no column to speak of in the first place.

```
GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;
GridView1.Columns['A'].Visible = false; // Hide sorting column A aka Data1 to the user
GridView1.Columns['B'].Visible = false; // Hide sorting column B aka Data2 to the user
```